# opening pdf files in electron

Tags: javascript, pdf, electron

I need to build an app where the user can open PDF files within the app -- i.e. not by opening a new browser window.  I would need to implement a back button and possibly some overlays over the PDF.  Does anyone know if there's a good way to do this in Electron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're OK with UI provided by chrome PDF extension you can use it from electron.

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true
    }
  })
  win.loadURL(__dirname + '/test.pdf')
})
```

*Note, that electron's native PDF support is available only since version `1.6.4` and has been broken from `3.0.0` until `9.0.0`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52844602/2550156) for details) For versions without support you can use [`electron-pdf-window`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-pdf-window)*

Comment: I did exactly that but it still starts a download instead of displaying it

Comment: See this question if you are using Electron 3.0.0 or later: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52844135/7910454

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout [gerhardberger](https://github.com/gerhardberger)'s [electron-pdf-window](https://github.com/gerhardberger/electron-pdf-window)