# How to view a PDF in an Electron BrowserWindow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron, chromium

So I have this Electron app and in one of the .html-files I link another script that provides some utility-functions to the program and one of those is this one:

```
function openPDF(filePath){
    let pdfWindow = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({
        icon: './build/icon.png',
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            plugins: true
        }
    });

    pdfWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: filePath,
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    pdfWindow.setMenu(null);

    pdfWindow.on("closed", function () {
        pdfWindow = null
    });
}
```

So this should use the integrated PDF-Viewer of Electron (which uses Chromium) to open the PDF in a new window. I used the infamous `plugins: true`, I tried through most of the [thousands of preferences you can define for a BrowserWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) but it always opens the window and then starts to download the file instead of displaying it.

I triple checked the file path, the "imports" etc., updated everything but I can't seem to find the problem. Electron natively supports this since [1.6.4](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v1.6.4) but it doesn't work for me.

Help me, Stack Overflow, you are my only hope.

Comment: Looks like a bug which is open for a long time https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12337

Comment: is this still the way to view PDF files in the `BrowserWindow`?

Comment: @oldboy, I'm sorry, I don't know. The remote module is about to be deprecated but the rest should be fine AFAIK.

Comment: turns out that u can now view pdfs natively using an `object` element and this is actually suggested by electron, whereas `webview` is discouraged at the moment. sucks tho cuz id like to modify or have greater control over the pdf viewer UI

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Update 2020:

@karthick correctly pointed out that this is a bug that disables the plugins despite `plugins: true`. [The Issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12337) exists [since 3.0.0](https://electronjs.org/blog/electron-3-0#other-notes) (September 18, 2018) and <s>remains to be fixed today</s> **has finally been fixed in Version 9!**

Update your electron version to 9.X.X or higher with this command to enable the functionality:

```
npm update electron
```

You can check the `devDependencies` in the `package.json` which should be found in your project folder. It should look something like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.0.0"
},
```

---

## Old answer:

As long-lasting GitHub issues tend to get rather confusing I will update this answer with the gist of the development. You can also find three workarounds at the end of the answer.

**Updates:**

1. March 19th: [A fix is on the way](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/17163).
2. May 19th: The fix mentioned above is currently on hold
   waiting for [better extension support](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/17440).
3. June 28th: [Better
   extension support](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/17440) is not expected to be there any time soon.
4. July 16th: [The fix](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/17163) is no longer being actively worked on. Quote
   of the developer:

> The main thing I ran into trying to port over Chromium's viewer was its dependency on the chromium extension system. Electron supports only a portion of that system which made it difficult to integrate the viewer.

5. July 25th: There has been significant progress with the [improvement of the extension support](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/17440) which was merged and a [follow-up tracking issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/19447) was created. This increased the likeliness of a continuation of the work on [the fix](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/17163).
6. August 28th: Right now no one is working on a fix. You can [put a bounty on this issue over on BountySource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/56240517-enable-pdf-viewer) if you want to see this solved more quickly.
7. November 19th: [The fix](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/17163) was closed and the branch deleted. Quote of the developer:

> We're still intending to one day restore the PDF viewer, but it relies on us first migrating to use Chrome's extensions library instead of our own shim, as the PDF viewer in Chromium is implemented as an extension.

8. January 2nd: Still no one is working on this despite [a bounty of $1,600 over on BountySource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/56240517-enable-pdf-viewer)
9. January 21st: Extension support is being improved continuously ([tracking issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/19447)) and a [new fix](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/21794) has been introduced.
10. February 13th: [The new fix](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/21794) has been merged and the issue has been closed. **Looks like this is going to be resolved in Electron 10!** Quote of the developer:

> This should be ready to test out in the next 10.x nightly. I'm hoping to backport to 9.x as well, though it may not end up sticking if it causes issues.

**Workarounds:**

1. You can make it work by downgrading to the latest 2.X.X. To do that use the following command:

   ```
    npm install electron@"<3.0.0" --save-dev
   ```

Keep in mind, however, that [only the latest three stable major versions are supported by the Electron team](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/support.md) which means **2.X.X is not receiving security patches anymore**.

2. Alternatively you could call on the system to open the file. It will choose the default program assigned to PDFs:

   ```
    shell.openItem(fullPath);
   ```

Just make sure that the path (`fullPath`) is always correctly resolved with something like `path.resolve(app.getAppPath(), filePath)` as it might change when you build the app.

3. Another workaround would be to use something like [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) which doesn't quite offer the full feature set of the Chrome PDF Viewer (e.g. missing field completion) but is probably good enough for most applications. Here is a sample implementation which catches the download-event and routes it to the PDF.js-viewer:

   ```
    const { BrowserWindow, session } = require('electron')
    session.defaultSession.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
        if (item.getMimeType() === 'application/pdf' && item.getURL().indexOf('blob:file:') != 0) {
            event.preventDefault();
            new BrowserWindow().loadFile(path.resolve(__dirname, `pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=${item.getURL()}`));
        }
    })
   ```

Comment: This isn't working. According to the package.config I'm on `"electron": "^13.1.2"` and I have added `webPreferences: { plugins: true }` to my BrowserWindow options. All I get is a garbled empty window with an empty PDF page navigation on the left...

Comment: @user3700562 Please create a separate question and I will try to.solve your issue. It seems like you did everything correctly.You could try downgrading to 12.x.x just to see if 13.x.x is the issue here.