# Open PDF packaged within Electron with External App

Tags: reactjs, pdf, electron, create-react-app, electron-builder

We would like to distribute a set of PDF files within our application. Originally we were opening these with a React PDF viewer however the users really need to be able to save these files to their computer so they can read/annotate/print these in their own time etc.

We are using Create React App within Electron - do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Managed to get this working using the following method:

```
PDFLink= (e)=> { // Open PDF with `shell` method
    console.log("Clicked PDF: ");
    var attrs=e.currentTarget.attributes;
    const shell = window.require('electron').shell;
    const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
    const appPath = remote.app.getAppPath();
    console.log('appPath: ', appPath);

    for (var a=0;a<attrs.length;a++)
    {
      console.log(attrs[a].name+"="+attrs[a].value);
      switch (attrs[a].name)
      {
        case 'data-pdf':
        //console.log(app.getAppPath());
        shell.openItem(appPath+'\\public\\pages\\test1.pdf');

          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are the PDFs already shipped along with your app?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52844135/7910454

Answer (score 1):

If the PDFs are shipped with your app, you could just use the [shell](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell) module to open them: [shell.openItem(fullPath)](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.36.10/docs/api/shell.md#shellopenitemfullpath).

> shell
>
> > Manage files and URLs using their default applications.
>
> shell.openItem(fullPath)
>
> > Returns Boolean - Whether the item was successfully opened
> >
> > Open the given file in the desktop's default manner.

Comment: I can trigger this to an external URL from my app which is great however I am unsure on the correct format the the file path of something within the application itself

Comment: Hmm, you could get the directory that your app is running at using [app.getAppPath()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetapppath) & then construct the path to where your shipped resources are located.

Comment: that could work, just need to be able to access getAppPath from react. Currently doing it like this: `const { app } = window.require('electron'); console.log(app.getAppPath());` but get the error : Cannot read property 'getAppPath' of undefined

Comment: Could you try specifying `remote`, like: `const { app } = window.require('electron').remote` ?