# Electron Nodejs - I need to make a pdf viewer embedded in the web content

Tags: node.js, pdf, webview, electron

I'm making an application to sign pdf's and I need to make the pdf of it can be seen in the web container, that only the first page can be seen, that it can not be navigated, that it does not have a tool bar, that it can not be zoomed, only one preview of it. I could do this with the version of Electron 1.8.8, with the later versions it is not possible, because it makes me a download of the pdf, I need electronic features of newer versions. some have an idea how to do to see the pdf as in the example image.

[Example with Electron 1.8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmfLz.png)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844135/view-pdf-in-electron-browserwindow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View PDF in electron BrowserWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844135/view-pdf-in-electron-browserwindow)