# Can i open file with an electron app on a computer with only a simple archlinux without desktop?

Tags: electron, archlinux

I have a electron app that connect to a intranet. This app run on a Raspberry Pie with archlinux. I dont have any desktop install on archlinux, the app is launch on startup with xserver.  On the intranet you can download file (mostly .docx and .pdf).

Can i open those file with my electron app?

When i try to download a file, electron show a prompt to chose where to download the file but there is no save button. With the app you can also acces google drive using a webview.

I want to be able to open the file, i have no need to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open PDF files. Electron's native PDF support has been available since version 1.6.4. Usage:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      plugins: true
    }
  })
  win.loadURL(__dirname + '/test.pdf')
})
```

If you're running an older version, you'll need to use something like `electron-pdf-window` ([gerhardberger/electron-pdf-window](https://github.com/gerhardberger/electron-pdf-window)).

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45880748/1392578/

Ref: [Electron PDF viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220321/)

To open `DOCX` files, you'll definitely need either a native OS app or a third party library like [evidenceprime/html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js)

Comment: See this question if you are using Electron 3.0.0 or later: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52844135/7910454